# Converting between European and US dates with +0000 on the end

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the date format from European to US (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) so far I know this should work:

```
          var dateString = array[4];
            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var newDateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            //inserting the new date and time into the array
            array[4] = newDateString;
```

Input: `14/Dec/2014:15:25:34`

However, if i look at the new file the output is in the following format:

```
14/12/2014  15:25:34
```

EDIT:: The error came from this line in my code:

```
 writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))))
```

When changed to 'string.Join(", "... the format was correct.

Comment: The debugger converts the DateTime variable into a string using your local culture preferences.  You know it actually worked correctly, 14 is not a valid month.  You don't have a real problem.

Comment: @HansPassant it doesn't work correctly.. working correctly would give me an output with the date in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'? Or am i missing something..?

Comment: Your code works just fine. Debug it and in `newDateString` you'll get `2014-12-14 15:25:34`. So the problem must be,if i understand what you're doing, when your write this in a new file

Comment: It must be, I've only noticed this error recently and i'm 99% sure it was inputting correctly into my .csv file before, which is why i was confused to see it not formatting correctly

Comment: @johnfish92 is it at all possible that by some coincidence you developed the application this winter, live in a winter time UTC+00 timezone and the errors started to appear the moment when summer time hit in?

Comment: @grek40 i've edited the question with the error.. it was being cause by having no space when seperating the elements in the array. No idea why this would affect the format however it has and everyting is working okay. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `zzz` as UTC offset format specifier

```
var dateString = "24/Oct/2014:13:52:12 +0100";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var newDateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

However, for timezone sensitive information, you should probably work with `DateTimeOffset`, it gives you more control for different timezones.

If you have to deal with multiple formats but still want to use exact parsing, use the overload that accepts a format array (and DateTimeOffset as mentioned):

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateString, new[] { "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss zzz", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Comment: If i change my code to this it throws an error basically saying that this format isn't what dateString is holding. On debugger it actually shows the date/time as being in the format: "14/Dec/2014:15:25:34". But yet when passed into newDateString it still gives out the format as seen in the question. Any ideas as to why? Is there an error in my code of formatting newDateString?

Comment: Please be specific... is the string containing an UTC offset or not? `"14/Dec/2014:15:25:34"` doesn't work with `zzz` but `"24/Oct/2014:13:52:12 +0100"` does.

Comment: When looking at the debugger i noticed that '+0100' for some reason wasn't being stored in dateString, however i still have a slight feeling it is stopping the correct formatting as i have edited the question with my code and cannot see why or where it would be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your format string to

```
"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss K"
```

for working with the UTC format.

have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.
You can use

```
"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

as well.